# Copying arabic text in Windows

Tags: wordpress, excel, copy-paste, arabic

I have translated Arabic content in Microsoft Excel. Whenever I am copying it to my Wordpress site with Polylang Arabic language support, the letters get messed up like this:

الهاتف (اختياري)

Although the original text was like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/39E6V.pnge]

I'm using Windows 7 with Office 2010 and this applies to every application I want to copy to. I've installed Arabic support for Windows and have tried both copying and pasting with Arabic keyboard as well as English. No luck.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied you text into Google and it formats it correctly, like in your image. You will need to set proper right to left layouts when ever you use these.

Try

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        Some text that is right to left...<p>
        الهاتف (اختياري)<p>
    </head>
</html>
```

Try the above code, this will display the *wrong* Arabic you gave to properly formatted Arabic.

The Important part is this, it sets the text direction to right-to-left `"rtl"` and language to Arabic `"ar"`:

```
<TAG dir="rtl" lang="ar">...</TAG>
```

You can use `dir=` and `lang=` with quite a few tags in HTML.

Comment: Actually I discovered the problem wasn't so bad I first thought. Although the text might seem scrambled in Wordpress editor, it displays on the website, which is probably as you mentioned due to HTML text direction tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [right-to-left mark character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark):

```
الهاتف (اختياري)&rlm;
```

Without `&rlm;`:

الهاتف (اختياري)

With `&rlm;`:

الهاتف (اختياري)‏